# What effect cold climate could have on reptilean demi-humans?

Tags: climate, reptiles

In this world, there are reptilean demi-humans (like lizardmen and lamia) which are appearance wise half-human half-reptile, they live in coexistence with humans and other types of demi-humans. These reptileans are poikilothermics (cold-blooded), so in theory they would be vulnerable to cold temperatures and usually seek warm places if possible.

Knowing that these half-human half-reptiles monsters (essentially humans with reptile traces and characteristcs), how could some characteristcs of the reptiles, like being cold-blooded, translate to daily life?

For example: would a reptilean demi-human student have distance education during winters for example? Or maybe heaters being used with more frequency?

How could cold climates affect them in general? Could it be lethal or dangerous to be in cold weather? Or maybe just affect their reflexes and/or disposition? Generate a tendency to hibernate (or brumate)?

Comment: A poikilotherm is just as afraid of heat as it is of cold. Poikilothermic animals are not able to regulate their internal temperature and will just as easily overheat. The immediate consequence is that poikilothermic animals simply cannot be too active and definitely cannot sustain intense effort. The human brain alone dissipates some 20 W of heat, and it does it continuously; how that would work in an animal which cannot regulate its internal temperature is a big question.

Comment: Depends on their tech level. Please specify.

Comment: @kleer001 It is like our current tech level I would say. It is a multispecies society based on our current time.

Comment: So, a critter that has the possibility of "distance education" (meaning some kind of telecommunication presumably at least the level of telephones) does not know about warm clothes? Ok then.

Comment: @puppetsock Oh that's a good idea that I hadn't thought yet xD thanks a lot!

Comment: Note a cold blooded animals is going to have a hard time supporting something as energetically expensive as a large brain. 1/3 rd of all the calories a human eats go just to running the brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Clothes.**

[image: reptile in parka]

Lizardmen are usually depicted strutting around in the buff, or with some kind of scanty loincloth.  There is definitely a place for that.  But cold lizardmen would want clothes, and thick ones.  It would be even more important for them than for us mammal types.  Warm clothes would let them retain the metabolic heat they make with muscles.  These warmly-clad lizardfolk would also keep moving; flexing, squatting, posturing, shimmying side to side; doing whatever they needed to do to generate that heat from their muscles.

Answer (score 3):

Many real world reptiles and amphibians slow down in colder weather, hence why they develop special ways to absorb heat from the suns rays. Some species, for instance, can hibernate under frozen rivers in mud, or straight up freeze themselves too. You can read some here, [its called cryptobiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptobiosis). Because of different types of reptiles and amphibians, the affect of cold weather (and how harsh it becomes) severely depends on how you will build your species. If cold winters are common, it would be natural for the demi-humans to have some sort of biological tactic to deal with the temperature drops.

As for education, perhaps your reptilian demi-humans have a winter break rather than a summer break (if conditions are not extreme). Winter would likely slow them down if they cannot control their inner temperature, thus impacting education.

Answer (score 0):

There your reptiles might have evolved to survive the cold to some degree or not even have a problem with it like some amphibious animals. The temperature should impact them regardless because the reaction speed of chemical processes will go slower in the cold. That’s like when we humans have not enough sugar , or oxygen in the blood what slows us down in speed, power in the muscles or process speed in the brain. But just as with us humans proper clothing and controlled activity can circumvent such problems. 
Intelligent reptiles however would need extra heat sources to take with them while a human takes the energy in through food and produce the heat themselves, that is also why species like humans eat more in comparison.

Comment: They would be essentially half-human half-reptiles monsters, humans with reptile traces and characteristcs. I want to know how some characteristcs of the reptiles, like being cold-blooded, could translate to daily life.